# AuthGuard not being invoked on Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router-guards

Im trying to implement a guard on my angular 9 project to check if the user is authenticated, but the `canActivate` method is not being invoked on the "sample" route that i'm trying to guard.

this is my main module where i'm trying to implement the guard:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path      : 'sample',
        component: SampleComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers   : [
        AuthGuard,
        ...
    ],
    exports     : [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

this is the guard class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        public authService: AuthService,
        public router: Router
    ) { }

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated !== true) {
            window.alert('Forbidden');
            this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

AuthService `isAuthenticated` and `getToken` methods

```
    get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        console.log('token' + this.getToken());
        if (this.getToken() === null) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getToken());
        }
    }

    getToken(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, please help me.

Comment: Did you log the value of `this.authService.isAuthenticated` in `canActivate`?

Comment: Please share the `isAuthenticated` method.

Comment: I edited the question and i added the `isAuthenticated` and `getToken` methods from `AuthService`

Comment: @T.SunilRao I did, and is not printing the value in the console

Comment: Everything seems fine. Are there other routes routing elsewhere?

Comment: Yes ! the SampleComponent actually has it's own module with a router inside

Comment: it's seems something to do with the routing structure it seems. Can you share it?

Comment: The problem was, the route being called was the one inside SampleModule, i added the guard at that module and it worked, thank you @T.SunilRao

Comment: Great! Glad you could solve it